# Clean up very long list of company names - apply function on each row of data.table

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I have a data.table with company names and address information. I want to remove legal entities and the most common words from the company name.
Therefore I wrote a function and apply this to my data.table.

```
search_for_default <- c("inc", "corp", "co", "llc", "se", "\\&", "holding", "professionals", 
                     "services", "international",  "consulting", "the", "for")

clean_strings <- function(string, search_for=search_for_default){
     clean_step1 <- str_squish(str_replace_all(string, "[:punct:]", " ")) #remove punctation
     clean_step2 <- unlist(str_split(tolower(clean_step1), " ")) #split in tokens
     clean_step2 <- clean_step2[!str_detect(clean_step2, "^american|^canadian")]  # clean up geographical names
     res <- str_squish(str_c(clean_step2[!clean_step2 %in% search_for], sep="", collapse=" "))   #remove legal entities and common words
     res <- paste(unique(unlist(str_split(res, " "))), collapse=" ")  # paste string together
     return(res) }

datatable[, COMPANY_NAME_clean:=clean_strings(COMPANY_NAME), by=COMPANY_NAME]
```

The script works well. But when I have a large dataset (>3b rows) it takes very long.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

**Examples:**

Input:

```
Company_Name <- c("Walmart Inc.", "Amazon.com, Inc.", "Apple Inc.", "American Test Company for Consulting")
```

Expected:

```
Company_name_clean <- c("walmart", "amazon.com", "apple", "test company")
```

Comment: can you add some examples of how `COMPANY_NAME` looks like? So that we can run some tests...

Comment: I will add examples

Comment: shouldnt `Amazon.com, Inc.` become `amazon com` instead of `amazon.com` as you wrote?

Comment: Yes, "Amazon.com, Inc." becomes "amazon.com"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
library(stringr)

words <- c("corp", "co", "llc", "se", "&", "holding", "professionals", "services", 
           "international",  "consulting", "the", "for", "american", "canadian") |> 
           paste0("\\b", ...= _, "\\b", collapse = "|")

others <- c("inc\\.", ",") |> paste(... = _, collapse = "|")

Company_Name |> 
  tolower() |> 
  str_remove_all(pattern = paste0(words, "|", others)) |> 
  str_trim()
```

A few notes:

1. In your code, you match all punctuation. You actually don't want that, as it would take the dot out of `amazon.com`. Just match the things you need.
2. 3 billion rows is a lot! It's unrealistic to expect any script to run *fast* on this kind of dataframe. *Faster than what you currently have* is possible though
3. If you can decrease the number of rows in some way (e.g. by removing duplicates) that would be great
4. Searching for things like "co", you are going to get false positives, like matching the co in "starbucks coffee". Match word boundaries ("\b") to remove this issue.